# Jupyter notebook custom.css in created environment

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

Does anyone know how to set custom.css in for a conda environment?

I created a new environment using

```
conda create -n myenv
```

But it doesn't use the same custom.css I created in the default environment.

Any idea where I should put the custom.css file to get Jupyter to use it?
I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs [here](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html) for info on where paths are located by default (for conda you'd probably be looking at the {sys.prefix}/etc/jupyter path).

Or you could just run `jupyter --paths` in your conda environment shell to find out where it is looking for custom files.

Comment: Thanks! Using the --path showed that the environment was installed at the location you specified. Then I had to copy my custom.css to  myenv\share\jupyter\custom\